# Rotating a UIViewController to Portrait when in Device Landscape in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, modalviewcontroller, deprecated

I am working with a Custom Video Camera.  To make recording easy I setup the camera an it's overlay to be in portrait, but look as if it was in Landscape.  This works for me as I want the videos to be taken width long due to the nature of the project.  Currently I'm having a challenge with iOS 6 to get my view controllers to rotate to portrait, and portraitUpsideDown when the device is rotated to landscapeLeft and landscapeRight.  Is there anyway in iOS 6 to tell the view controller to rotate to portrait when the device rotates to landscape?  Previously I would do this with shouldAutoRotateToOrientation

Currently I'm toying with these methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I've looked at a lot of the other documentation on stack overflow about these changes in iOS6 but haven't yet found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get working. We did for Landscape but you can do it for Portrait by modifying the code bellow:

First in the interface (this is only partial b/c of company policies i can't show you everything):

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView *myTableView;
    CGAffineTransform _originalTransform;
    CGRect _originalBounds;
    CGPoint _originalCenter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

Next here is the implementation:

```
@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize myTableView;

- (void)loadView {

    UIView *viewContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    CGRect tableFrame;
    tableFrame.origin.x += 10;
    tableFrame.origin.y -= 15;
    tableFrame.size.height = 320;
    tableFrame.size.width = 460;

    // create and configure the table view
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    myTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;    
    myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


    [viewContainer addSubview:myTableView];
    self.view = viewContainer;  
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    _originalTransform = [[appDelegate navController].view transform];
    _originalBounds = [[appDelegate navController].view bounds];
    _originalCenter = [[appDelegate navController].view center];

    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(3.14/2));
    //landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);

    [[appDelegate navController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

    [appDelegate navController].view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [appDelegate navController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
    //[appDelegate navController].view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[appDelegate navController].view setTransform:_originalTransform];
    [[appDelegate navController].view setBounds:_originalBounds];
    [[appDelegate navController].view setCenter:_originalCenter];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; 
}
```